# How to escape pound symbol in the json post body for jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have the end point which has the post body as json but it gives exception as json parse exception while the text is having pound symbol ('£') in jmeter however it works fine in postman.

```
{"value":[{"text":"Paying £45 a month ok for you?"}]}
```

If I remove £ symbol then it works fine in jmeter.

I have already mentioned header as Content-Type:  application/json in Jmeter.

Any thoughts please how to handle that pound symbol in the json body?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try amending `Content-Type` header to look like:

   ```
   application/json; charset=UTF-8
   ```
2. Make sure you run JMeter with the same encoding, add the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```
3. Set Content-Encoding to `UTF-8` in the HTTP Request sampler or even better in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so you wouldn't have to do this for all samplers individually.

   [image: JMeter Content Encoding]
4. And finally given your request works in Postman you should be able to record it with JMeter's [HTTP(S) test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).
5. Also consider upgrading to the latest JMeter version which is [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) as of now.